# Multiple request at same time in work manager and observe them

Tags: android, android-workmanager, observers

I want to download some files even when the app is killed. Currently I am using work manager to enqueue multiple one time requests. I have a few doubts,

1. Does making new  `OneTimeWorkRequest` everytime actually enqueues a different request each time?
2. How can I access the progress of the each requests? Either I want to observe progress of all requests all at once, I will then filter then out by tag or anyway I can put the requests sequentially and get the progress of each of them.

Here is my code so far.

```
Data.Builder data = new Data.Builder();
        data.putString("url", url);
        data.putString("path", path);
        data.putString("fileName", fileName);

        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                .build();
        OneTimeWorkRequest mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DownloadWorker.class)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(data.build())
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).beginUniqueWork("test", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,mRequest).enqueue();

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfosLiveData().observe(this, (Observer<List<WorkInfo>>) workInfos -> {
            if (workInfos.size() > 0) {
                WorkInfo info = workInfos.get(0);
                int progress = info.getProgress().getInt("progress", -1);
                String url1 = info.getProgress().getString("url");
                CurrentData.getCurrentData().setProgress(progress, url1);
                //Do something with progress variable
                contentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
```

And this is my worker file.

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        int downloadId = PRDownloader.download(Objects.requireNonNull(getInputData().getString("url")), Objects.requireNonNull(getInputData().getString("path")), Objects.requireNonNull(getInputData().getString("fileName")))
                .build()
                .setOnStartOrResumeListener(() -> {
                    Log.e("TAG", "download: start ");
                })
                .setOnPauseListener(() -> {
                    Log.e("TAG", "download: pause ");
                })
                .setOnCancelListener(() -> {
                    Log.e("TAG", "download: cancel ");
                })
                .setOnProgressListener(progress -> {
                    long progressPercent = progress.currentBytes * 100 / progress.totalBytes;
                    Log.e("TAG", "download: progress "+((int)progressPercent));
                    setProgressAsync(new Data.Builder().putInt("progress", (int) progressPercent).build());
                    setProgressAsync(new Data.Builder().putString("url", getInputData().getString("url")).build());
                })
                .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadComplete() {
                        Log.e("TAG", "download: completed ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Error error) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "download: error "+error.getServerErrorMessage());
                    }
                });

        return Result.success();
    }
```

Comment: did you find an answer?